# Java reference-type in parameter

Tags: java, reference

Why doesn't this change the initial object:

```
public class Foo
{
 Bar item = new Item(5);

 public changeBar(Bar test){
  test = new Item(4);
 }

 public run(){

  changeBar(item);

 }
}
```

In this case `item` doesn't get changed. How is this possible? I mean, you're passing the reference as parameter in the method, so I'd say assigning a new value to it, means the initial `item` would also be changed.

Can someone explain to me how this works.

=======================================

however, my question is the following:

the following does work right?

```
public changeBar2(Bar test){
 test.parameter = "newValue";
}
```

I don't see how that's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public changeBar(Bar test){
    test = new Item(4);
 }

 changeBar(item);
```

Here the value in `item` in copied to `test`. So as of now, both `item, test` are pointing to same object(s). Inside the method, `test` is pointing to a different location which doesn't affect the `item`. You are **passing by value** and not by reference.

---

```
public changeBar2(Bar test){
   test.parameter = "newValue";
}
```

The above modifies the object that is passed because both the `test` and `item` are referring to the same object.

So, `test` can totally either point to a new object or modify the object was earlier referring to. Both are different and are valid.

Comment: Okay thanks, I understand that. However, I've added a second part to the question. I think I really get it now, but could you perhaps explain the difference to me between my two examples?

Answer (score 3):

Consider a thought experiment:

```
changeBar(null);
```

Would your code above change the value of `null`?

The answer to your question is that although your `Bar` object is passed "by reference", this is different from passing the *reference itself* by value. In Java, all parameters are passed by value, even when they are themselves references to other objects.

Comment: Thanks! That last paragraph makes very much sense to me!

Answer (score 1):

Parameters in Java are ALWAYS passed-by-value.

At the beginnning of function changeBar() test is a reference to item, but then you overwrite it with a reference to a newly created item. You therefore only overwrite the local variable with a different reference, but don't change the referenced by object.

Answer (score 0):

`test` in `changeBar` is basically as pointer. So when you assign it, you are changing the pointer.

Here is an article: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the method the reference to this object, that is, its address so to speak. So this address is stocked in a variable named `test`.

Then your method erases what is written in the `test` variable, and writes instead the address of a new `Item` object it created. Nothing here changes anything to the initial `Item` object, nor to the references to it that are outside the method's scope.

I guess I am pretty approximative here and I will be glad to get corrected.